# How to properly maintain a testing version of a site?

Tags: localhost, testing

At my place of work we host many sites that almost all run Wordpress. Some of them are changed quite frequently, and emply e-commerce solutions such as WooCommerce. Consequently, these sites also use a lot of plugins, and as such need to be updated regularly.

Obviously, when doing updating and such, we like to test before we roll out changes on live. Up until now, we've been creating subdomains of our current sites for the testing sites, such that example.com has a copy of itself for testing at dev.example.com. We copy the old database and work off of that.

For those with experience...is this the best way to do this? I'm starting to think not. I like working locally and am starting to develop and test on localhost, and then use ngrok to share testing externally. Furthermore, I was wondering if there is any harm in connecting a live database to my localhost, testing site, so that changes to the live site and mirrored on the local, testing site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend wp-migrate-db plugin for copying local->live or live->local DB with ease. I too use a locahost setup for building/testing/sharing with others. Then when launching live use wp-migrate-db plugin to export DB, find/replace URLs, and import into live site. It's very straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Although I usually use a similar approach, I suggest you give sqlyog a try if you are in need of a professional solution that can quickly deploy mysql databases:
https://www.webyog.com/

For content, use rsync, which is the fastest way to synchronize local and online.

Hope it helps. Good luck.